# OL-Cesium - Example doesn't work

Tags: openlayers, cesium, ol-cesium

I would like to test the Ol-Cesium on my computer with this example:
https://openlayers.org/ol-cesium/examples/oldfashioned.html

I saved the `olcs.css`, `olcesium.js` and `Cesium.js` file into my webserver's folder. 
So, here is my code (I replaced only the lines where JS and CSS are located).

The 2D view with only OpenLayers is works well, but the 3D Cesium view doesn't. The map is black, and I got no error messages in console.

Do you have any tips what cause this error?

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css"
        type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="olcs.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
        #map {
            height: 300px;
            width: 500px
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="olcesium.js"></script>
    <script src="Cesium.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Old-fashioned example</p>
    <input id="enable" type="button" value="Enable/disable" />
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>

<script>
    var ol2d = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.transform([25, 20], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
            zoom: 3
        })
    });

    var ol3d = new olcs.OLCesium({
        map: ol2d,
    });
    ol3d.setEnabled(true);
    var setEnabled = function () {
        ol3d.setEnabled(!ol3d.getEnabled())
    };
    document.getElementById('enable').addEventListener('click', setEnabled);
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: `scene.globe.enableLighting = true;` should fix it.

Comment: is the globe really 3D? EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857 are both 2D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OL-Cesium works well with the main layer types (vector, raster, overlay).

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/ol-cesium/olcesium.js"></script>
<script src="https://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.62/Build/CesiumUnminified/Cesium.js"></script>
```

Example: [OL6 + OL-Cesium + Cesium](https://svelte.dev/repl/382b4c2ac0a5408a93de7848f00c4915?version=3.23.1)

Comment: Fine answer! It works! Thanks!

Comment: Hi, your Example does not work anymore, any update for the latest version?

Answer (score 2):

Just the file Cesium.js is not enough. You need the complete library which is what the example does.

You have two options, either download the 1.62 Cesium library cesium and import the Cesium.js as in the example or change this:

```
<script src="Cesium.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.62/Build/CesiumUnminified/Cesium.js"></script>
```